# Using Google Analytics for combined Native Mobile and Website analysis

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-analytics

I'm working on an app for a particular website that's currently using Google Analytics. I'm planning on adding Google Analytics to my iOS device as well. I want to know how to design my work flow so that I can merge both sources of data.

Should my mobile device be sending out data to a URL like my www.website.com/myPhone? Is creating a separate 'UA' (Google Analytics serial number) account for the phone a good idea? Any advise on viewing relevant meaningful data in one place would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A little more on what your site and your application do would be useful. But if they do the same things I recommend you to have 3 profiles in 1 account, and to use filters to do :

- one profile with all your stats
- one profile with your website only
- one profile with your mobile app only

Try to have the same URLs for the same views : this will facilitate the reading of statistics and the implementation of goals.